# Comparing strings in Python 3.2 difficulties

Tags: python, string, string-comparison

I have the following

```
if('y' == input("Enter y to continue")):
    # do something
```

But it doesn't work, no matter what I type?

Comment: Works fine here - what exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: I mean, it doesn't enter the conditional lines, even when I type 'y'. I'm running it from a Windows 7 command line.

Comment: what are you doing inside the conditional? paste the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug on windows, you can identify it by doing `print(repr(input("put y: "))`

Try this

```
input("put y:").strip().lower() == "y"
```

Comment: Yeah, windows turns it into 'y\r'. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: I can't reproduce that either (even after adding the missing parenthesis). Could you link to the bug report? In which Python versions is it present?

Comment: Can't reproduce it either - i.e. it works at least fine under my Win7 x64 install. Now crossplatform terminal support has more than a few "rough edges" especially under windows, so maybe it's a bug in older Windows versions?

Comment: I run Windows 7 x64, all patched up, and yet I can reproduce it.

Comment: @x74x61: Which *exact* Python version?

Comment: @x74x61 also what terminal are you using?

Comment: Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Feb 20 2011, 21:30:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 on Windows 7 x64 cmd.exe Microsoft Windows [versie 6.1.7601]

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce this here:

```
>>> if('y' == input("Enter y to continue: ")):
...    print("Yeah!")
...
Enter y to continue: y
Yeah!
>>>
```

But I would do it differently anyway:

```
answer = input("Enter y to continue: ")
if answer.lower().startswith("y"):
   print("Yeah!")
```

also handles `Y`, `Yes!`, `yes, please...` etc. correctly.

Comment: your own solution indeed does work, but I still can't figure out why mine doesn't.

Comment: Maybe you should copy the relevant contents of your Python shell and post them in your question. You must be doing something differently.

Comment: Tim, I think the problem is solved, but your solution is still better. I didn't do anything differently. See accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me on 3.2.1 on Windows 7 x64:

```
>>> if input("Enter y to continue") == 'y': print("ok")
Enter y to continuey
ok
```

("continuey" is correct, it's just "continue" + my "y" input.)

Answer (score 1):

I've just come across this issue, this is how I solved it (Python 3.4.1):

```
i = input ('Enter y to continue: ')
validity = i == 'y'

if validity == True:
    #do something
```

By using the Boolean type to identify whether the input was equal to y you are avoiding the bug, it's extremely simple too.

Answer (score 0):

use `if input("Enter y to continue").lower().startswith('y'):`.